# Setting the positioned fixed element width of the parent div not working

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, css-position

I am trying to fix position element, and to take the full width of the parent div. This is my html:

```
     <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="player-avatar-card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="avatar-image">
              <img src="/imagecache/small/{{ $player->image_filename }}" alt="Profile Image" class="rounded-circle">
              <img class="flag rounded-circle" src="/icons/flags-round/{{ $player->nationality }}.svg"></h3>
            </div>
            <h5>{{ $player->first_name }} {{ $player->last_name }}</h5>
            <p>{{ $player->nationality }}, {{ $player->age }} years</p>
            <div class="social-buttons">
              <div class="col-12">
                <a class="btn btn-info btn-lg" href="#" role="button">
                  <i class="ion-plus-round"></i> follow</a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12">
                <a class="btn btn-info btn-outline-info" href="#" role="button">
                  <i class="ion-android-share-alt"></i> share</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I am giving the position fix class to `player-avatar-card`, on scrolling to element:

```
  const avatarCard = document.querySelector('.player-avatar-card');
  const fixClassAvatar = 'is-fixed-avatar';

  function stickyScroll() {
    if( window.pageYOffset > 56 ) {
      avatarCard.classList.add(fixClassAvatar);
    }
    if( window.pageYOffset < 56 ) {
      avatarCard.classList.remove(fixClassAvatar);
    }
  }
  $(window).scroll(stickyScroll);
```

And this is the class:

```
.is-fixed-avatar {
  position: fixed;
  max-width: inherit;
  width: 100%;
}
```

But, the element goes out of the `col-md-3` div, how can I fix that?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/p9229sak/) is the fiddle. Make sure to expand it on the screen, so that it is wide enough to see it working.

Comment: By making an element absolute, static or fixed, you take it out of the flow of the page, so it is no longer considered to be inside it's container and can't be limited by it.

Comment: Is there a way around this without using js?

Comment: Its difficult to tell without more context or seeing the code that includes it.  For example is the is the left-most column? In that case, it might be possible to make it permanently fixed to the left hand side, and add padding to the main content to counteract it. But like I said, without more info, its difficult to know.

Comment: Yes, it is the left most column, I will try to make a fiddle out of it, so that you can get the full picture.

Comment: I made a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/p9229sak/

Comment: Not really sure what are you trying to do, but position sticky might be right option for you.

Comment: I have tried with position sticky, but that didn't work, the element wasn't fixed

Comment: So, to be clear, you want an element to ACT like position:fixed, but have it be fixed to the inside of its parent, and NOT to the inside of the viewport?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `position: fixed`, the div is taken out of the flow and consequently taken out of the `col-md-3` div. I propose to make it `absolute`:

```
.profile-content .player-info .is-fixed-avatar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Now you can use *jQuery* to place some *stickiness* to the `avatar` - check it by minimising the window height. See a simplified demo below (the last `section-card` is inside the `col-md-9`):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const avatar = $('.player-avatar-card');
  const avatarBox = avatar.parent();

  function sticky() {
    var offset = avatarBox.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
    if (offset >= 0) {
      avatar.css('top', '0');
      return;
    }
    avatar.offset({
      'left': avatar.offset().left,
      'top': -offset + 90 // 90px to adjust for padding
    });
  }
  $(window).scroll(sticky);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  color: #484848 !important;
}

.is-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
}

.page-nav {
  height: 56px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f1eeee;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background: #fff;
}

.page-nav .section-links .active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #008489;
  color: #008489;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.page-nav .nav {
  height: 56px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.page-nav .nav .nav-link {
  height: 56px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 100px;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #484848;
}

.lg-strong-font {
  font-size: 34px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #e90052;
}

.lg-strong-font span {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.profile-content {
  padding: 2rem 0;
  background: #f7f7f7;
}

.profile-content .info-content {
  padding-left: 3rem;
  padding-right: 3rem;
}

.profile-content .title-margin {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.profile-content .title-icon {
  color: #008489;
  margin-right: 1.7rem;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

.profile-content .info-title-hr {
  margin-left: 3rem;
  margin-right: 3rem;
}

.profile-content .section-card {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  border: 1px solid #f1eeee;
}

.profile-content .sub-section {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.profile-content .icon-wrapper {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.profile-content .icon-wrapper i {
  color: #008489;
}

.profile-content .video-section {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: -5px;
}

.profile-content .video-section .profile-video-box {
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.profile-content .player-info .icon-box {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 8px;
}

.profile-content .player-info .player-info-card-content {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.profile-content .player-info .is-fixed-avatar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.profile-content .player-info .player-avatar-card {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1.5rem 0;
  border: 1px solid #f1eeee;
  background: #fff;
}

.profile-content .player-info .player-avatar-card .card-body {
  width: 100%;
}

.profile-content .player-info .player-avatar-card p {
  margin-bottom: 0.2rem;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  color: #7b7b7b;
}

.profile-content .player-info .player-avatar-card .avatar-image {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  display: inline-block;
}

.profile-content .player-info .player-avatar-card .avatar-image img {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}

.profile-content .player-info .player-avatar-card .avatar-image .flag {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: -5px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
}

.profile-content .player-info .player-avatar-card .icon {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.profile-content .player-info .player-avatar-card .card-title {
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
}

.profile-content .player-info .social-buttons {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.profile-content .player-info .social-buttons .btn {
  border-radius: 200px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}

.profile-content .player-info .social-buttons .btn i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.profile-content .table>thead>tr>th,
.profile-content .table>tbody>tr>th,
.profile-content .table>tfoot>tr>th,
.profile-content .table>thead>tr>td,
.profile-content .table>tbody>tr>td,
.profile-content .table>tfoot>tr>td {
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 0 !important;
}

.profile-content .table>thead>tr>th {
  text-align: center;
}

.profile-content .table>thead>tr>th .icon-wrapper {
  margin: auto;
}

.profile-content .table>thead>tr>th,
.profile-content .table>tbody>tr>td {
  max-width: 110px !important;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.profile-content .table>thead {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f1eeee;
  background: #fff;
}

.profile-content .table-responsive {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.profile-content .no-data-message {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
}

.profile-content .years {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.profile-content .info-label {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  color: #7b7b7b;
}

footer {
  height: 20rem;
  padding: 20px 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #3c3e42;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.4);
}

footer h4 {
  font-weight: 700;
}

footer a {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.search-result {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.search-result .search-list {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.search-result .query-card {
  color: #fff;
  background: #00bcd4;
}

.search-result .query-card .card-block {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.search-result .search-list-media .media img {
  width: 160px;
  height: auto;
}

.search-result .media {
  margin-top: 10px !important;
}

.search-result .media-body p {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding-top: 0 !important;
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.search-result .tab-content {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.search-result .pagination,
.search-result .tab-content {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.contact-form .card {
  padding: 1rem;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 20;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  color: #008489;
  padding: 45px;
  padding-top: 3rem;
  background: #333;
}

.menu a {
  color: #e4e4e4;
}

.menu h4 {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.menu .btn {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.push-menu-left {
  top: 50px;
  width: 280px;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: -4px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: -4px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.push-menu-left {
  right: -285px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid page-nav">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9 offset-md-3">
        <nav id="page-nav" class="nav section-links">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#info">Info</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#videos">Videos</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#stats">Statistics</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="profile-content">
  <div class="row player-info">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="player-avatar-card is-fixed-avatar">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="avatar-image">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Profile Image" class="rounded-circle">
                <img class="flag rounded-circle" src="http://via.placeholder.com/32x32">
              </div>
              <h5>Name</h5>

              <div class="social-buttons">
                <div class="col-12">
                  <a class="btn btn-info btn-lg" href="#" role="button">
                    <i class="ion-plus-round"></i> follow</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                  <a class="btn btn-info btn-outline-info" href="#" role="button">
                    <i class="ion-android-share-alt"></i> share</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <div id="info" class="player-info-card-content section-card">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                <h5><i class="ion-ios-list-outline title-icon"></i> Overview</h5>
                <hr class="info-title-hr">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row info-content">
              <div class="col-12">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-6 col-md-3 player-info-data">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-12 info-box">
                        <span class="info-label">Born</span>
                        <p>Born</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-6 col-md-3 player-info-data">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-12 info-box">
                        <span class="info-label">Club</span>
                        <p>Club</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-6 col-md-3 player-info-data">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-12 info-box">
                        <span class="info-label">Position</span>
                        <p>Position</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-6 col-md-3 player-info-data">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-12 info-box">
                        <span class="info-label">Height</span>
                        <p>180 cm</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-6 col-md-3 player-info-data">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-12 info-box">
                        <span class="info-label">Weight</span>
                        <p>75 kg</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-6 col-md-3 player-info-data">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-12 info-box">
                        <span class="info-label">Foot</span>
                        <p>Both</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-6 col-md-3 player-info-data">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-12 info-box">
                        <span class="info-label">Agent</span>
                        <p>Pro sports agency</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="section-card">
            <div id="videos" class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <h5 class="title-margin">
                  <i class="ion-ios-videocam-outline title-icon"></i> Videos
                </h5>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row video-section">
              <div class="col-12">
                <div class="info-content">
                  <p></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 profile-video-box">
              <a href="">
                <div class="card bg-dark text-white">
                  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="card-img" />
                  <div class="card-img-overlay">
                    <div class="play-icon-wrapper">
                      <i class="ion-ios-play"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-content">
                      <h5 class="card-title">title
                      </h5>
                      <p class="card-text">date
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="section-card">
            <div id="stats" class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <h5 class="title-margin">
                  <i class="ion-ios-pulse-strong title-icon"></i> Performance data
                </h5>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                  <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>
                          <div class="icon-wrapper">
                            <i class="ion-android-calendar"></i>
                          </div>
                          <span class="info-label">Season</span>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                          <div class="icon-wrapper">
                            <i class="flaticon-football-trophy-cup"></i>
                          </div>
                          <span class="info-label">Competition</span>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                          <div class="icon-wrapper">
                            <i class="flaticon-soccer-t-shirt"></i>
                          </div>
                          <span class="info-label">Club</span>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                          <div class="icon-wrapper">
                            <i class="ion-ios-football-outline"></i>
                          </div>
                          <span class="info-label">Goals</span>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                          <div class="icon-wrapper">
                            <i class="flaticon-football-strategic-sketch"></i>
                          </div>
                          <span class="info-label">Assists</span>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                          <div class="icon-wrapper yellow">
                            <i class="flaticon-football-yellow-warning-card"></i>
                          </div>
                          <span class="info-label">Yellow cards</span>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                          <div class="icon-wrapper red">
                            <i class="flaticon-football-card-with-cross-mark"></i>
                          </div>
                          <span class="info-label">Red cards</span>
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="text-center">17/18</td>
                        <td class="text-center">NO</td>
                        <td class="text-center">Odd</td>
                        <td class="text-center">5</td>
                        <td class="text-center">3</td>
                        <td class="text-center">0</td>
                        <td class="text-center">0</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: I was hoping for some css solution, since this one doesn't look smooth, it is flickering on scroll.

Comment: I guess there are no *CSS only* solutions here... I couldn't see any flickering?

Comment: Sorry, I guess it was just flickering when I was testing it in safari, but now it looks ok. I will accept your answer as the correct one, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to achieve what you want.

**Option 1**

First, you can set the element you want fixed and the element that you want to scroll under it into a master element. Then set both of them to `position: absolute` and set `overflow: scroll` to the content element. In this example, the parent *does not scroll*, which is why the fixed element does not move.

CSS

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden; // Just to guarantee that no scroll appears
}
.fixed-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 20px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="fixed-menu"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

**Option 2**

Similarly, you can create a child that is absolutely positioned, then create a grandchild that contains the fixed content. If you *do not set the top/bottom/left/right* of the fixed grandchild, it will remain fixed wherever the child sat.

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 25%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px; // Same size as the grandchild for easier positioning
    height: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    right: 50px;
}

.grandchild {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: red;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    Content...          
    <div class="child"><div class="grandchild"></div></div>
</div>
```

**Option 3... Sort of**

Third, you can create a set of local coordinates for children of an element by setting either `will-change: transform` or `transform: translate*(0)`. This puts the element on its own render layer, and thus provides its own coordinates.

CSS

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    transform: translateX(0); // I used X, but any will do.
}

.child {
    position: fixed;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 25px;
    right: 25px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    Content...      
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

I'm unsure as to what has happened with this option. It previously worked in all browsers save for Internet Explorer, but now, in all modern browsers, the `fixed` element is simply acting like an `absolute` element in that it does *not* remain fixed, it instead will scroll with the content of the parent. I have done experiments and found that, by switching on and off CSS attributes on the parent in Chrome Dev Tools, that I can cause Chrome to glitch and render the child fixed to the parent. This is only a glitch, though, and it returns to rendering the first way after a refresh. Thus, I assume that this implementation decision is explicitly intentional.

**Conclusion**

You have two ways and the potential third way to achieve what you want. I'm still playing around with the third way since it does not follow what I remember, and the glitch that achieves what I want seems to indicate that the possibility is there, but for now it is just experiments.